# Recolor image to other base color and keeping the gradients

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to recolor an image to another base color but thereby keeping the gradients. For example in this picture the base color is green.

[image]

and I want to change this to base color Blue for example (RGB: 0,119,153). I used the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
dg = [0,59,10]
mg = [0,91,16]
lg = [0,106,18]
db = [92,71,0]
mb = [153,119,0]
lb = [204,163,93]

im = cv2.imread("C:/Temp/recolor_source.png")
im[np.where((im == dg).all(axis=2))] = db
im[np.where((im == mg).all(axis=2))] = mb
im[np.where((im == lg).all(axis=2))] = lb
cv2.imwrite("C:/Temp/recolor_result.png", im)
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

There is still quite some green around the white text and in the grayed-out button in the resulting image. What is the right approach to convert to another base color and keeping all the gradients?

Comment: You may try converting to HSV colourspace and taking all Hues between 110..130 (i.e. greens) and adding 80 degrees to them to make them blues https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV Except be aware that OpenCV uses 0..180 rather than 0..360 so you would need to halve those numbers. Then convert back to regular BGR.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. This indeed does the trick. :). Just for completeness, all colors will be turned 80 degrees now. So we could first identify the specific green areas by color detection (e.g. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/15/determining-object-color-with-opencv/) and then do the conversion only for the ROI's. The conversion itself is added as a separate answer to my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer as suggested by Mark Setchell.

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("C:/Temp/recolor_source.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hchannel = hsv[:, :, 0]
hchannel = 40 + hchannel
hsv[:, :, 0] = hchannel
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imwrite("C:/Temp/recolor_result.png", rgb)
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Comment: Cool - well done and thank you for sharing back with the community. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Note that you can achieve the same thing just using **ImageMagick** at the command line to modulate the Hue like this `convert widget.png -modulate 100,100,150 result.png` That means... *"leave the Brightness and Saturation unchanged at 100% of their existing values and modulate the Hue to 150% of its original value"* See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate